# AngularJs user validation making request for every characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, request

Hi i'm using an User Name validator in my project.But when I started writing some thing it's requesting for every characters after reach min length.
Here you can see in pic.

[image]

Here is my soruces;

Input parse in page:

```
<input type="text" id="regUserName" name="regUserName" required minlength="5" maxlength="15" class="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı" data-ng-model="regUserName" username-validator />
```

And here validator in ValidationService.js:

```
angular.module('BlogAppModule').directive('usernameValidator', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function (username) {
            return $http.get('/api/CheckUserName/' + username)
            .then(function (response) {
                var warning = document.getElementById("regUserName");
                if (response.data != null) {
                    warning.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
                else {
                    warning.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                }
            })
        }
    }
};
```

});

Now here my some questions about this:

1. Will be a problem about this requests?(Like performance problem)
2. Can I set this validation like when I leave the textbox then check
   username?If this is possible, what should I do?
3. When user write "." requesting don't work.How can I disable in
   textinput special chars like : " . - , ! # " etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, changes will be written back to the model on every change.
Use `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` on the `input` element to update the binding when leaving the input field.

If you want to add client side validation as well, you can add a synchronous validator. `$validator`s will be executed before `$asyncValidators`s.

```
  link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function (username) {
          // your server side validation
      };
      ngModel.$validators.userNameOk = function(username) {
        return username && username.indexOf('.') < 0;
      };
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yd8C8Ut9VWPXEvDEMjFJ?p=preview

Comment: Thankyou so much my friend.Worked correctly . And do you know something about my 3rd question? I dont want Usernames which include dot,comma etc. characters.

Comment: @CoderWho you need to handle that on server side..because passing character like `.`, `:`,etc. are potential dangerous while sending through the URL..you must have getting error while sending those request..